# simple jQuery toggle() not working

Tags: jquery

I have:

```
<style>
   #dom {display:none;}
</style>

<ul>
    <li><span id="adom">DOM related</span>
    <div id="dom">
      <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Four</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("adom").click(function(){
    $("dom").toggle();
  });
});
```

but clicking "Dom related" does not toggle the display of #dom.

[Here is the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SRD75/XN6eh/)

Comment: You have to use the [**ID selector**](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/). `$("adom")` tries to select an element with **tag name** `adom`. This is explained in the [jQuery tutorial about selecting elements](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/), which you should have read :)

Comment: `$("#adom")` instead of `$("adom")`

Comment: @FelixKling: add an answer and I'll choose it Felix.

Answer (score 1):

use # for the ID selector:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#adom").click(function(){
    $("#dom").toggle();
  });
});
```

Updated JSFiddle at:

http://jsfiddle.net/XN6eh/2/

Answer (score 0):

problem is you didnt mentioned either adom is .class or #id. Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/XN6eh/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#adom").click(function(){
    $("#dom").toggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? What's the problem? Please **explain** your solution.